# How to split a display into many and access all the screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, hdmi

I'm trying to split the screen in raspberry-pi. 
and access each screen for each display

I want the multiple layer in a single screen. Eg. my output screen resolution is 1024x720 in that i have to split vertically into two. in that i can play one video in one side and another video in another side.

Comment: Are you using a Pi 4 (i.e. with two HDMI ports)?

Comment: You can find the screen settings in Preferences > Screen Configuration.

Comment: @MikePoole Im using pi3b+. In that i want to split a screen into two and access both screen

Comment: What do you mean by "split a screen"? How many physical screens do you want to connect?

Comment: Which screens will you be using? The Pi3 only has one HDMI. I would recommend using a Pi 4 (they are back in stock) because it has two HDMI ports and can be used to display different images.

Comment: i want the multiple layer in a single screen. Eg. my output screen resolution is 1024x720 in that i have to split vertically into two. in that i can  play one video in one side and another video in another side

Comment: Just use 2 instances of omxplayer with specific screen coordinates.

Comment: Please edit your question and add additional information to it. There is a link named [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/105406/edit) below the question. Don't use comments.

Comment: @CoderMike I tried but it works. I want play every media. image,video, urls etc

Comment: @TejeshTeju as mentioned update your question with this important information.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to split screen and and use different software there is multitask option in windows 10 and in windows 11 you can see it in maximize option on the top right corner.

If you still have doubts you can check it on youtube by searching 'How to split screen in windows'

Comment: What has Windows got to do with it?